# Investigate convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Formula represented on this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqdu7.png) :

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(3^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)\sin \frac{\pi}{n}$$

I know that this is convergent but how can I show it?

Comment: Use the Taylor series of $\sin\pi x$ and $3^x-1$ around $x=0$ to show that the factors behave as $\frac{1}{n}$ for large $n$, and their product like $\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: @Bernstein: I don't have a pen at hand, so I might be mistaken, but I think the ratio test for $3^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is inconclusive.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos I can't use Taylor series

Comment: @Bernstein it tends to 1

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

We have that

$$\left(3^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)\sin \frac{\pi}{n}=\left(3^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)\frac{\pi}{n}\frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{n}}{\frac{\pi}{n}} =\frac{\log 3}{n}\,\frac{e^\frac{\log 3}{n}-1}{\frac{\log 3}{n}}\,\frac{\pi}{n}\,\frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{n}}{\frac{\pi}{n}}$$

then use [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) with $\sum \frac1{n^2}$.

Comment: Solved)
Thanks a lot.